# Accessing intermediate armadillo object member without naming it [C++]

Tags: c++, armadillo

Using the armadillo library, one may write

```
// Log if this is non-finite
if ( ! averages.is_finite() )
{
    arma::uvec nonfinites = arma::find_nonfinite( averages );
    LOG_WARN( "There are ",  nonfinites.n_elem, " of ", averages.n_elem,
            " non-finite elements in the band border averages of the input signal." );
}
```

I'd like to simplify this without using the `nonfinites` intermediate vector, like so:

```
    LOG_WARN( "There are ",  (arma::find_nonfinite( averages )).n_elem, " of ", averages.n_elem,
            " non-finite elements in the band border averages of the input signal." );
```

But I get a g++ error message

```
/path/to/file.cpp:901:71: error: ‘arma::enable_if2<true, const arma::mtOp<long long un
signed int, arma::Mat<double>, arma::op_find_nonfinite> >::result’ has no member named ‘n_elem’
         LOG_WARN( "There are ", (arma::find_nonfinite( averages )).n_elem, " of ", averages.n_elem,
```

I'm unsure if I'm dealing with a general C++ issue or if the arma library function return type is not an `arma::uvec`  (as indicated by the g++ error). which actually has the member `n_elem`. Is it required to convert the returned object into an `uvec` first?

Many thanks in advance for any explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.eval()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eval_member) member function to forcefully evaluate the expression:

```
(arma::find_nonfinite( averages )).eval().n_elem
```

Alternatively, directly convert the expression to `uvec`:

```
arma::uvec(arma::find_nonfinite( averages )).n_elem
```